# Why doesn't "Like" match a query when equal does?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following query, a match is found:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE originalpath =
  "d:\\pic16\\160623 bugs\\RW2-jpg\\P1280627.jpg";
```

However, a match is not found using "Like":

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE originalpath Like
  "d:\\pic16\\160623 bugs\\RW2-jpg\\P1280627.jpg";
```

I get the same result using "\" before the " ", ":", "-", and ".":

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE originalpath Like
  "d\:\\pic16\\160623\ bugs\\RW2\-jpg\\P1280627\.jpg";
```

How can I make the match using `Like`?  (Mysql 5.6, Innodb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is because you need to **slash** every slash when writing an expression try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE originalpath Like "d:\\\\pic16\\\\160623 bugs\\\\RW2-jpg\\\\P1280627.jpg";
```

While writing an expression then because certain characters can have a different meaning they need to be escaped in order to show that they are literal.

Comment: Thanks! That's it.